# If value is greater than, less than and becomes greater than again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with my following logic.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/2aCa7/)

**The logic**

```
var budgetCalc = function (financeBudget, totalCost, remainingBudget, changeOn) {
    var reloadCalc = function () {
        var formula = parseFloat($(financeBudget).val()) - parseFloat($(totalCost).val());
        $(remainingBudget).val(Math.abs(formula.toFixed(0)));

        if ( formula >= 0 ) {
            $('.toolbar-budget').addClass('is-positive').append('<p>Remaining</p>');
        } else {
            $('.toolbar-budget').addClass('is-negative').append('<p>Over Budget</p>');        
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Price Input
        $(changeOn).change(function () {
           reloadCalc();
        });
        $(changeOn).trigger('change');             
    });
};
```

**What works fine**

The interface has multiple selects, inputs and a jQuery sliders that change the value of `formula`. The logic works fine when the page loads and the formula value is `>= 0`. If the value is `< 0` than the `formula` works fine as well.

**The Issue**

If the value of the formula is `< 0` and then becomes `> 0` again because the user changes the values contributing to `formula`, the logic does not change the class back to `.is-positive` unless the page refreshes.

**My goal**

I want the class of `.is-positive` to be applied without the page refreshing if the value goes from `< 0` to `>= 0`.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and a jsFiddle?

Comment: I added a jsfiddle of this http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/2aCa7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the simplest solution would be to remove both classes before adding the appropriate one but adding `$('.toolbar-budget').removeClass('is-positive is-negative');` before your check:

```
$('.toolbar-budget').removeClass('is-positive is-negative');
if (formula >= 0) {
    $('.toolbar-budget').addClass('is-positive').append('<p>Remaining</p>');
} else {
    $('.toolbar-budget').addClass('is-negative').append('<p>Over Budget</p>');
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2aCa7/2/)**

Comment: That's awesome. Is there a way to remove the .appends from constantly written over and over again? Ideally I only want one. I can always hide them with an overflow, but it's not as clean.

Comment: Awesome it works perfectly. Took me a while to notice the <p></p> that was added, don't know why. Slow day I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You use `addClass()` and do not clear existing classes, so you end up with both classes set. You should remove previously set classes via `removeClass()` or `toggleClass()`.

Also, I'd recommend to do the same with `.append('<p>Remaining</p>');` part, so you don't just append paragraphs but swich them.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to best implement that. I've added a jsfiddle sample of how it works. See here http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/2aCa7/

Comment: @dvoutt, simply remove the opposite class, `$('.toolbar-budget').removeClass('is-negative').addClass('is-positive')`. The counterpart is left as an exercise to the reader